# Attempting to write constructors for subclass inheriting from class, guessing at syntax, expected-primary-expression error?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have a class Sphere that inherits from class Shape (for a homework project):

Within Shape I have three constructors.  The declarations from Shape.h are as follows:

```
Shape();
Shape(Vector);
Shape(Vector, float[]);
```

Within Sphere my constructors inherit from these constructors.  The declarations in my Sphere.h file are as follows:

```
Sphere(): Shape() {}//line 17
Sphere(Vector, float): Shape(Vector) {}//line 18
Sphere(Vector, float, float[]): Shape(Vector, float[]) {}//line 19
```

My syntax here is based largely on looking at templates.  While my first language was C++, I was unfortunately taught other concepts, like inheritance, only in Java.

Anyway, I have the following error messages upon `make':

```
Sphere.h: In constructor ‘Sphere::Sphere(Vector, float)’:
Sphere.h:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
Sphere.h: In constructor ‘Sphere::Sphere(Vector, float, float*)’:
Sphere.h:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
Sphere.h:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
```

Can you help me understand these messages and what might be causing them?  I first tried letting them be expressed in the typical way, i.e., instead of

```
Sphere(): Shape();
```

and then describing the constructor itself in the .cc file, I did as I had seen done in some online tutorials, without really understanding why:

```
Sphere(): Shape() {}
```

This didn't change anything, the problem remained.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your constructor declarations (not in the .h), the parameters need names so that it knows what to store them as.

Comment: Kris, this is the .h file.  So is this not as it should be?  I thought in the .h file it should just list parameter types.

Comment: Normally in C++ you separate declaration and implementation.  The type-only parameter specifiers are OK in the declaration (`.h`) although even there I prefer having named params ... but you definitely need names in the implementation (`.cc`) as others have noted.

Comment: The prototypes don't need names, so the first code block you posted is fine. The second one, the -- definitions? I'm bad with terminology... -- need to have the variable names. And yeah, as David said, it's good practice to separate the two. The prototypes usually go in a separate .h file, while the method implementations go in their own .cpp file.

Comment: In this case though -- since you're only calling the superclass ctor -- it's acceptable to have the ctor "inlined" in the header.  I mostly point this out because Java/C# do *not* separate interface and implementation this way.

Comment: `Within Sphere my constructors inherit from these constructors.`  The terminology isn't quite correct here.  You aren't *inheriting* the constructors of the parent, you're using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify names, not just types, for the parameters, and pass the names, not the types. For example:

```
Sphere(Vector a, float b, float[] c): Shape(a, c) {}
```

Comment: This was it!  I didn't get that I shouldn't pass type into the used superclass constructor!  Thanks, Jerry.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given your constructor arguments any names.

This is ok, so long as you don't actually want to use those arguments!

Comment: Everything I've looked at says that the prototypes for constructor arguments in the .h file just list variable types, and the actual definition line where it's implemented in the .cc file gives names to those arguments.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization list belongs in the constructor's implementation and isn't part of the constructor's declaration (or prototype). You seem to be putting it with both.

You can either do:

```
// Sphere.h
struct Sphere {
  Sphere();
};

// Sphere.cpp
Sphere::Sphere() : Shape() {

}
```

Or you can do:

```
// Sphere.h
struct Sphere {
  Sphere() : Shape() { }
};

// Sphere.cpp
// No constructor here; you defined it in the header.
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but I'm getting similar errors.  I followed your advice, so now my second constructor is prototyped as Sphere(Vector, float); in the .h file, and implemented as Sphere::Sphere(Vector pos, float rad): Shape(Vector) {/*code goes here*/} in the .cc file.  I now get the following error: Sphere.cc:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token